# Cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am trying to iterate through a hiddenfield that has been populated with fileID's by javascript. I've tried it like this :

```
foreach(string exhibit in hidExhibitsIDs.Value.Split(','))
{
    comLinkExhibitToTask.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExhibitID", exhibit);
}
```

but I'm not sure if it will in the id as a string to the db.(my property in my DB is int so I'm guessing that is why my stored procedure isn't working.) I am trying to iterate the loop as an int like this :

```
foreach (int exhibit in hidExhibitsIDs.Value)
{
    comLinkExhibitToTask.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExhibitID", exhibit);
}
```

I've tried doing `int.Parse(hidExhibitID's.Value)` etc but it gives me the error above.

Comment: [How to: Convert a string to an int (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop won't just magically cast a comma delimited list of numbers into an enumeration of integers.  You were on the right track before using the `Split()` method of `String`.  However, you'll then need to convert each value to an integer using `Convert.ToInt32()`.

Something like:

```
foreach(string exhibit in hidExhibitsIDs.Value.Split(','))
{
   comLinkExhibitToTask.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExhibitID", Convert.ToInt32(exhibit));
}
```